# Why are some of my files are being corrupted when downloading via ftp?

Tags: php, ftp, corruption

Does anyone have any idea why my files are being corrupted?

I have a very odd file corruption issue that is causing havoc in our small office. The issue occurs when we download files using ftp from our web server to our local server. If we move approximately 2000 files all at once there is usually about 10 files that will be altered during the download (but never the same files).

Here's the facts:

- The file downloads from the remote server without generating any errors.
- The file will download with a slightly smaller file size. (this amazes me it doesn't generate an error)
- The file when opened will be missing a chunk of content.
- The missing content has been anything from 3 lines to 50 lines.
- The missing content is never consistent, it can start mid word and ranges as to what position in the file it gets removed from.
- The file is not jumbled or corrupted in any other way. It literally looks like someone selected some content and hit the delete button.
- The file type has been php, javascript and jpg
- We have had this issue when downloading large groups of files and also when downloading a single file.
- This issue is happening to 3 out of 4 developers in our office.
- This issue is happening regardless of the ftp clients used.
- This issue is happening regardless of where the files are being downloaded to    (internal server/local PC/external drive)
- This issue started happening about 4 months ago. We have been using the same software and hardware for years and there is nothing I can think of that has changed.

Prgramming is my usual domain and I am completely clueless with this sort of thing so if anyone has any ideas or things to investigate you might need to use small words :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you set the binary\text transfer correctly, the ftlp client needs to know what file is what type

Comment: Is the point of commonality the web server? Exactly what server software?

Comment: @Dagon We did look into that as it seems to be the main cause for corrupt files but we all have it set to auto and has been that way for the last 5 years without any issues.

Comment: @Matthew Gunn Yes the web server is the point of commonality (which i know very little about unfortunately) which is running LiteSpeed V6.7 
We have an external server administrator I can harass if needed :)

Comment: If I were trying to go full out crazy on this, I'd write some code using Apache commons FTP client or something that just hammers the web server and then records if/when it gives me crap output.